How to Identify the Source of Programmatic Access for an Active IAM Access Key in DynamoDB?
I am trying to identify the source of programmatic access for an IAM user's access key that shows regular activity (e.g., last used 1 hour ago, 30 minutes ago etc.). Despite replacing this key, the activity persists. After extensive research, I found in the IAM credential report that this key is being used for DynamoDB operations and on dashboard it is marked as 'Programmatic access with active access key.'
dashboard activity
credential report
I have reviewed all the places where our application accesses DynamoDB, but I am still unable to pinpoint where this specific access key is being utilized. How can I accurately locate the service that is using this IAM access key for DynamoDB access?
I have tried the following steps to locate the usage of the IAM access key:
Credential Report: Generated an IAM credential report to confirm the access key's activity.
Code Review: Checked all application codebases and configuration files for the old access key.
Replaced Key: Replaced the access key, expecting the activity to stop.
Despite these efforts, the access key activity continues, indicating that it is still being used somewhere in our system. I expected to find and remove the old key from all locations, but the activity persists. Any suggestions on how to accurately locate and stop the usage of this IAM access key would be greatly appreciated.

What do you mean when you say that you "replaced the access key"? Can you simply locate and deactivate the access key in IAM (assuming you have IAM permissions)?

@jarmod I need to replace this key with another user's key.

Worth understanding the difference between identity-based policies and resource-based policies. Identities can have policies that grant permissions (e.g. IAM users can have dynamodb:PutItem permissions) but resources can also have policies that allow/deny IAM principals, so even if two different IAM users have DynamoDB permissions, you can add a resource policy to a given DynamoDB table that will deny one of those users access to the table.

Locating the key could be difficult without leveraging AWS Premium Support, as you may have allocated that key to any device/server.
A simple way to block all access to the key is to use a Deny policy for your DynamoDB tables, this can either be done through a Service Control Policy SCP policy or a Resource Based Policy RBP.
With SCP you could block all access to DynamoDB for that user, with RBP, you would need to block access for each table.

How will implementing a Deny policy on DynamoDB affect my application if it relies on writing and reading data to and from DynamoDB?

You only block the role that is using the access keys you don't expect to be used. Your application should be using different access keys so will be unaffected.
